# Best way to test a series of items

Tags: javascript, arrays, optimization

I'm looking for some advice to a simple pattern. That is, checking a series of things against some test. Needs to work IE8+

Normally, I would do something simple which seems appropriate for small tests (i.e. < 3 items):

```
if (someTest === 'one' || someTest === 'two' || someTest === 'three' ) {
  // do something
}
```

But lately I've been thinking about other ways to do the same thing:

```
var arrayOfSomething= ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
var arrayLength = arrayOfSomething.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  if ( someTest === arrayOfSomething[i]) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

The first method seems more readable and actually requires less code (assuming the list is small) and doesn't require two additional variables. The second method is more efficient, less redundant but also more complex and less readable.

Am I over-thinking this? Is there an optimal method?

Comment: Second can be write to `if (arrayOfSomething.indexOf(someTest) >= 0)` now its simple enough.

Comment: second one is much better and not very complex.

Comment: Note, that your second snippet is not equivalent to the first one.

Comment: @fuyushimoya IE8 doens't support `indexOf`

Comment: Just a note to anyone confused about `indexOf` support, IE8 does not support `indexOf` for Arrays but it is supported for Strings.

Answer (score 1):

IE8 doen't support `indexOf`

To be cross browser, use https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

```
if ($.inArray(someTest,arrayOfSomething) > -1) {
    // do something
}
```

**Edit**

From JQuery source code :

```
inArray: function( elem, arr, i ) {
    var len;

    if ( arr ) {
        if ( indexOf ) {
            return indexOf.call( arr, elem, i );
        }

        len = arr.length;
        i = i ? i < 0 ? Math.max( 0, len + i ) : i : 0;

        for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
            // Skip accessing in sparse arrays
            if ( i in arr && arr[ i ] === elem ) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }

    return -1;
},
```

Comment: I would prefer a vanilla JS solution.

Comment: @skube So, check the JQuery inArray source code to get their optimized code.

Comment: This is very interesting and seems like an ideal approach and solution. My only hesitation is not fully understanding the pattern.  It seems optimized to a degree beyond my skill. Also, doesn't seem easily readable (at least to me). It is probably a goal to strive towards however.

Comment: @skube in summary, use indexOf if you can, else use your solution.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, boolean evaluation on Javascript is lazy, meaning that a boolean expression ends evaluating as soon as its result is known.

This means that javascript engines won't evaluate your entire expression

```
if (someTest === 'one' || someTest === 'two' || someTest === 'three' ) {
  // do something
}
```

If `someTest === 'one'` it will stop evaluating and execute the if clause.

I'd, however, personally prefer something like

```
var myTestValues = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
if (myTextValues.indexOf(someTest) != -1) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: This is interesting but I think @sdespont is correct, `index.Of` is not supported on IE8, which is actually news to me.

Comment: @skube This is correct. indexOf is an ideal solution in this case. For IE8 just include conditional [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill).

Answer (score 0):

This works well in some cases:

```
switch (someTest) {
  case 'one':
  case 'two':
  case 'three':
    // do something
}
```

Short-circuiting behavior is the same as your original fragment. Some might say this is more readable. It also works better if there are multiple groups.